# Using += when inputting values into a 2D matrix in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix-multiplication, undefined-behavior

I'm writing code for matrix multiplication of 2 matrices, with sizes `n1,n2` and `n2,n3`.

This is what I tried:

```cpp
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n1 = 3;
    int n2 = 3;
    int n3 = 3;
    
    int arr1[n1][n2] = {
        {1, 2, 3},
        {5, 6, 7},
        {9, 10, 11}
    };
    int arr2[n2][n3] = {
        {2, 0, 0},
        {0, 2, 0},
        {0, 0, 2}
    };
    int res[n1][n3];

    for (int c = 0; c < n3; c++) {
        for (int r = 0; r < n1; r++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
                res[r][c] += arr1[r][i] * arr2[i][c];  // This is the main part
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n3; j++) {
            cout << res[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output was:

```
6422058 1877910233 1878006934 
1878000406 20 7022734 
7022746 68 22
```

Then I tried to change the line which had `+=`:

```cpp
int res[n1][n3];

for(int c = 0; c < n3; c++){
    for(int r = 0; r < n1; r++){
        int val = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < n2; i++){
            val += arr1[r][i] * arr2[i][c];    // Here I used new variable val
        }
        res[r][c] = val;
    }
}
```

The problem disappeared.
Output:

```
2 4 6 
10 12 14 
18 20 22
```

Why did this fix the problem?

Comment: Your code uses *variable-length arrays*, and such arrays are not allowed in C++. Use `std::vector` if the sizes are not known at compile-time (or needs to be resized at runtime). Or use `const` or `constexpr` values for the array sizes.

Comment: `int res[n1][n3]` is not even a valid C++; Even if `n1` and `n3` are constants, the array remains uninitialized, so your program output is undefined.

Comment: Also the arrays `res` are not initialized. Each element will have *indeterminate* values, and using them in any way (like you're doing with `+=`) will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Side note: About [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)...

Comment: About VLA: Not legal in C++, but why do they still compile??? They are legal in C and many C++ compilers are able to compile C as well; they then import the VLA feature from C to C++ as an *extension*. Using VLA, though, you rely on such compilers, your code is not fully portable. If you happen to compile with GCC or clang I'd recommend adding `-Werror=vla` to the compiler flags to avoid accidental use of VLA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that on the line:

> ```cpp
> int res[n1][n3];
> ```

all of the memory inside of `res` is going to be indeterminate, not zero.
That's why such nonsensical and large values are being printed out.
It's a symptom of *undefined behavior* in your code.

> ```cpp
> int val = 0;
> for(int i=0; i < n2; i++){
>     val += arr1[r][i] * arr2[i][c];    // Here I used new variable val
> }
> res[r][c] = val;
> ```

This fixes it, because you start with `val = 0`, then add onto it, and write the result to `res[r][c]`, so there is no undefined behavior here.
However, you could have also just written:

```cpp
int res[n1][n3] {};
// or
int res[n1][n3] = {};
// or
int res[n1][n3] = {0}; // C-compatible
```

... at the top, and this would have initialized all of the elements in `res` to zero.
All of these do the same thing.

#### Note on VLAs

All of your arrays are [Variable Length Arrays (VLAs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), which is not allowed in C++. You would have to make their sizes `constexpr`, or at least `const` to fix this:

```cpp
constexpr int n1 = 3;
constexpr int n2 = 3;
constexpr int n3 = 3;
```

Your code only compiles because the compiler supports VLAs as a non-standard extension.

Comment: @Akshat Just for the case you ever see (or even prefer yourself…): `int res[n1][n3] = { }` is just as fine, doing exactly the same; it's older syntax from pre-C++11 times.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know about this VLA thing, which is also why I was confused that even though I am not using heap memory my arrays have variable size.